# how to move a picture box diagonally on button click vb 2010

Tags: vb.net, winforms, vb.net-2010

I have a project that I am working on where I would like a picturebox to move diagonally on a button click. I've tried using  `PictureBox1.Left = 10`  and `PictureBox1.Top = 10` but that makes it so it goes left once and top for the rest of the button clicks. I would like it so when i click the button, the picturebox moves diagonally once and not multiple times separately. Is there any way where this is possible? This is the code I have so far

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    PictureBox1.Left -= 10
    PictureBox1.Top = 10
End Sub
```

---

Added from comments

I've tried the timer but it made the same mistake as the button. This is the code for the timer.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick 
    PictureBox1.Left -= 10 
    PictureBox1.Top = 10 
End Sub
```

Comment: Please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask At the moment it's difficult to guess what you want to do and what the problem is. Please post some code that you already have.

Comment: You can change left and top multiple times if you want an animation. You can use a timer controls and add to the left and top your step for the movement.

Comment: I've tried the timer but it made the same mistake as the button. This is the code for the timer.                                                                                                  Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        PictureBox1.Left -= 10
        PictureBox1.Top = 10
    End Sub

Comment: You are moving the `PictureBox` to `Y=10` and only move it to left each time. You need to set `PictureBox1.Left -= 10` and `PictureBox1.Top -= 10`. It this what you are looking for?

Comment: @RezaAghaei, this is somewhat what I am looking for, I would like it so that it shows the animation while it is moving

Comment: If you want it to show the "animation", you'll have to move it by `- 1` instead of `- 10`.

Comment: To show it as animation, you can use a timer with interval = 100 and change left and top -=1.

You can increase the speed by decreasing the interval and increasing the movement.

Comment: By the way, You can accept an answer by click on check mark near the answer. While you can only accept one answer but when you reached to 15 reputation, you can vote for as many answer as you find helpful, including the accepted one. To learn more see [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem in your code is you are moving the `PictureBox` to a fixed Y position = 10  and only changing it's x position by -10 each time.

So it doesn't move diagonally and it jumps to `Y=10` and moves to left each time you click on button.

You need to set:

```
PictureBox1.Left -= 10
PictureBox1.Top -= 10 'Here you used PictureBox1.Top = 10
```

To show it as animation, you can use a timer with `interval = 100` and change left and top `-=1`.

You can increase the speed by decreasing the interval and increasing the movement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the [`Location`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location(v=vs.110).aspx) of your picturebox, instead of each axis individually. Something like this.

```
PictureBox1.Location = New Point(PictureBox1.Left - 10, PictureBox1.Top + 10)
```

Comment: although this does work, I would like it so that it shows the animation as it is moving.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by show the animation, this will show the movement of each step. if you want it to be smoother use smaller increments